# Error When I try to launch TideSDK desktop App (I use TideSDK Develoer)

Tags: tidesdk

I am trying to launch the hello world sample,I use TideSDK 1.3.1-beta with Tide SDK Developer,I have install all the needed components such as imagick,wix and python 2.7 ,But I am getting this error during launch :

```
Preparing to package and launch desktop app. One moment...
C:\Python27\\lib\site.py:158: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
C:\Python27\\lib\linecache.py:127: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
C:\Python27\\lib\linecache.py:127: Warning: 'with' will become a reserved keyword in Python 2.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\tidebuilder.py", line 36, in
import env
File "C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\env.py", line 32, in
import app
File "C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\app.py", line 34, in
import os, os.path as p
File "C:\Python27\\lib\os.py", line 63, in
import ntpath as path
File "C:\Python27\\lib\ntpath.py", line 12, in
import warnings
File "C:\Python27\\lib\warnings.py", line 6, in
import linecache
File "C:\Python27\\lib\linecache.py", line 127
with open(fullname, 'rU') as fp:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Done launching!
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem , Since TideSDK comes with its own Python runtime,I created an environmental variable pointing to that python runtime so this was how I did it . [code] variable home : PYTHONHOME variable vaulue : C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\python\1.3.1-beta

Comment: And Again,I think its good to use python 2.5,from my terrible experience

Comment: Finally,I have settled on python 2.5.4 ,Its working better for me

Comment: really strange, i use 2.7.2 (albeit on OSX) without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems like it's using a different Python version, although the folder clearly says 2.7. Did you have another version of Python installed before? If so, did you change the environment variable to point to 2.7 after installing 2.7? Maybe confirm with python --version.

Comment: I had python v3 installed,but I uninstalled it and reinstalled the v2.7.I have set up the environmental variables to point to C:\python27 dir.

Comment: what does "python --version" say?